# Does lazy val on a Future prevent an actual database call?

Tags: scala, future

I want to conduct a query like this:

1. Query for a record on a specific date;
2. if (1) fails, then Query for a record on a range of dates, taking the last date.

The way I'm handling this now is:

```scala
lazy val specific: Future[Option[QueryResponse]] = // some database call

lazy val range: Future[Option[QueryResponse]] = 
  // some database call returning Future[Seq[QueryResponse]]
  .map { qrs =>
    if (qrs.nonEmpty) Some(qrs.maxBy(_.date)(_ compareTo _))
    else None
  }

for {
  s <- specific  
  r <- range
} yield {
 (s, r) // match on combination of Some/None
}
```

Two questions:

1. Does lazy prevent evaluation of the database call? I'd like as few calls to be made as possible. This is as much a language question as anything else.
2. Recognizing that 1 database call must be made regardless, it's probably best to make the call for a range and then filter locally on the POJOs to find the latest date, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands now, your code will execute both `specific` and `range` despite them being lazy. Consider the following simplified snippet

```
  lazy val specific = Future(Some("specific"))
  lazy val range = Future(Some("range"))

  (for {
    s <- specific
    r <- range
  } yield {
    (s, r)
  }).foreach(println)
```

which outputs

```
(Some(specific),Some(range))
```

where we see both executed. The nature of for-comprehension means both of them ran despite being declared lazy. If you want `range` to execute only if `specific` returns no result, then consider doing something like so

```
specific.flatMap {
    case Some(v) => Future(Some(v), None)
    case _ => range.map {
      case Some(v) => (None, Some(v))
      case _ => (None, None)
    }
  }.foreach(println)
```

which outputs

```
(Some(specific),None)
```

where we see `range` did not run.

Scalaz simplifies the problem to

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture.futureInstance

OptionT(specific).orElse(OptionT(range)).map(println)
```

which outputs

```
specific
```

which means `range` did not run.

Comment: This is not right. `range` will only be executed if `specific` succeeds.

Comment: @Tim If specific returns Future(None) range will still run.

Comment: Yeah, the more I look at this the less clear it becomes! I was assuming that a database failure would fail the `Future`, but maybe it just returns `None`.

Comment: This is ingenious. Thank you. Any comment on whether this is the "correct" approach? Would filtering over the range and finding the latest date be more efficient, since a database call is going to made either way? I'm assuming that some sort of study on the statistical likelihood of the first request failing would inform this decision.

Comment: @franklin It is hard to tell without actually observing how it performs in the real world. My suggestion would be try with just `range` and if you find performance lacking, then add in optimisations.